# laravel passport giving Unauthenticated error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel passport but when I try to hit the post route that gives me user data it's giving me error like

> {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

here is my controller method

```
public function getDetails()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
    }
```

api.php

```
Route::post('register', 'API\PassportController@register')-

>name('register');
Route::post('login', 'API\PassportController@login')->name('login');


//Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@getDetails')->middleware('auth:api');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
 Route::get('user', 'API\PassportController@user');
 Route::post('details', 'API\PassportController@getDetails');

});
```

screenshot of postmen

[image]
please let me know what inputs you want from my side

Comment: Have you configured your config/auth.php with the passport driver and added the \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class to your kernel middlewaregroups' array ?

Comment: yes @JeuneApprenti i have added

Comment: And sorry i've forget but have you registered passport's routes with Passport:routes and is your model requested using the Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens traits ?

Comment: yes i have added

Comment: i have the same problem of this

Comment: Authorization tab in postman includes a Bearer, I think you need to place it on there.

Comment: currently i am having error in admin controller like attempt method not found

Comment: does laravel/passport supports multi auth?

Answer (score 3):

Your codes look ok to me, but if I'm not mistaken you added your "Authorization" manually: please try this way from the image below, by clicking on Authorization tab, left next to Headers tab.

[image]

And make sure that your token is the one that is returned from the server when you  make login request: see the image below.

[image]